# Does Hyper-V support GPT disks on the host?

Tags: hyper-v, storage, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, gpt

Are there any issues with Hyper-V (on Server 2008 r2) if the host is formatted as GPT? Someone out there has tried this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there any issues with Hyper-V (on Server 2008 r2) if the host is
>   formatted as GPT?

EUFI/EFI based systems can boot to a GPT disk, all can use GPT disks as secondary disks.

> Someone out there has tried this...

Yes, yes they have.

Comment: I will also confirm this, as I have 2 Hyper-V deployments using nothing but GPT disks for storage.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is just Windows in this regard.  It boots from anything Windows boots from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm that it does work with GPT disks. I have 3 Hyper-V deployments, one CSV based and the other two using standalone environments connected to a storage array using iSCSI.

The two standalone are using GPT as they are allocated 3TB of storage each.